# I get an error when I want to upload an apk to Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play

I've trying to upload a new version of my app in Play Console. I used the same file to signed the APK. But Google Play sends me the next error:

[image: Google Play Console Error]

The error says that I upload a APK file that is not signed with the same certificate. It shows the fingerprinting. However, I see the same fingerprinte that I need when I review the certificate.

[image: Fingerprinter in console]

Could anyone give me a clue about the solution or what I have to review. I don't know what happens. Thank you

Comment: did you actually generate the apk using signkey? or just use the apk generated when doing on-device test? because this is the usual suspect...

Comment: Yes, I have the first version in production.This errors presents when I want to update the apk with a higher versioncode

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you aren't signing the APK with the keystore you think you are. You can check the certificate used to sign the APK by doing:

`keytool -list -printcert -jarfile foo.apk`